# $X_n + Y_n$, all $X_n$ are iid across n, all $Y_n$ are iid across n, limiting distribution?

Tags: probability-distributions, weak-convergence

$X_n$ are iid across n, all $Y_n$ are iid across n.
Can I caonclude that $Z_1=X_1+Y_1$ has the same distribution as $Z_2=X_2+Y_2$, $Z_3=X_3+Y_3$... $Z_n=X_n+Y_n$? $X_i$ and $Y_i$ may be dependent.

Comment: If $Z$ is a standard normal, then so is $-Z$, and $Z+Z =2Z$ is obviously not distributed as $Z+(-Z)=0$...

Comment: To make @BrianMoehring example more explicit, consider $X_n$ i.i.d. standard normal and $Y_i = (-1)^i X_i.$ Then $X_i + Y_i = 2X_i$ for $i$ even and $X_i + Y_i = 0$ for odd $i.$ You can modify this even further as $Y_i = (-1)^i X_i + G_i,$ where $G_i$ follow _any_ distributions. In this way you obtain a sequence $Z_i$ which contain a subsequence following any distributions.